# Get server URL in Program.Main of a Blazor WebAssembly app

Tags: blazor, webassembly

I want `Program.Main` in my Blazor WebAssembly app to make a call to the server that served the app before booting up the app - so I can grab some configuration settings from the server.

Is there a way to determine what the server URL was?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I can make a server request in `Program.Main` like this

```
private static Task<ClientConfiguration> GetClientConfigurationAsync()
{
    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddBaseAddressHttpClient()
        .BuildServiceProvider();

    var httpClient = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>();
    return httpClient.GetJsonAsync<ClientConfiguration>("api/client-configuration");
}
```